# Visual Studio crashes when trying to accses Toolbox -> COM Componets

Tags: visual-studio, com, crash, toolbox

Visual Studio crashes when trying to access Toolbox -> COM Components
This happens on my desktop dev PC with VS 2015 Pro and 2017 Community.

I also tried it with visual studio in SaveMode (from the command line using: devenv.exe /SafeMode). In SafeMode VS does not crash but most of the VS UI stops working.

I tried on my laptop VS 2015 Pro an there it works fine. So it must be something I installed on my desktop dev machine.

Any clues how to find the source of the problem?

UPDATE:
I found a simple workaround to activate a COM Component. Just drag and drop the .ocx file into the Toolbox and it will be available.

Comment: SysInternals' Process Monitor might point the finger to the evil-doer.

Comment: Thanks Hans unfortunately I wasn't able to figure it out with the Process Monitor. Do you know is its possible to change the settings in COM Components by editing a VS config file? I'll just need to activate one specific Component so I can use it in the tool box.

Comment: Never mind found a workaround.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/